# Formula for sum of odd or even or all numbers from x to y?

Tags: sum, series

I think the title covers it.

Most of the formulae I've seen produce the sum of even or odd numbers from 1 to n. I expect I could work out how to generalise by subtracting the lower range from the higher range, eg:

For sum of odds from 49 to 157:

(Sum of all odds -> 157) - (Sum of all odds -> 45).

What I've heard though is there's a general formula out of which all three problems falls, in which you give the first and last numbers and the interval between them and you're done?

It isn't proving easy when I'm trying to write a program that can take user input of any two values, and provide an answer every time:

Sum of odds from 1 - 99?
Sum of odds from 2 - 98?
Sum of evens from 1 - 99?
Sum of evens from 2 = 99?
Sum of evens from 3 - 3?

etc, including the sum of all numbers from 1 - 99... etc.

I'm guessing this is not a hard question and somebody will have an easy solution for it?

How would you do it?

Comment: Why not work out the formula yourself given the correct idea you had of taking the differences between 2 applications of the formula for the range 1 to n?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is purely math-based and not programming - would be a better fit at [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Sum of odd numbers from 1 to 2n is `(n - 1)` squared: eg. `1 + 3 + 5 = 9` which is 3 squared. `1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16` which is 4 squared.

For a series not starting at 1 simply subrtact the smaller square : `(1 + 3) + 5 + 7 = 16`,
Subtrating bracketed terms is `16 - 4` or `4^2 - 2^2 = 12`.
Generally: a..b odd integers,
Sum is `((b-1) / 2)^2 - ((a-1) / 2)^2`, both a and b included in sum.

Comment: wouldn't it be ((b + 1) / 2)^2 - ((a - 1) / 2)^2? For example, from 3..7: ((7 + 1) / 2) ^2 - ((3 - 1) / 2)^2 = (8 / 2)^2 - (2 / 2)^2 = 4^2 - 1^2 = 16 - 1 = 15. The formula given in the answer yields: ((7 - 1) / 2) ^2 - ((3 - 1) / 2)^2 = (6 / 2) ^2 - (2 / 2)^2 = 3^2 - 1^2 = 9 - 1 = 8, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

For odd all odds from a to b, regardless of whether a or b are odd or even:

`((b + (b mod 2)) / 2)^2 - ((a - (a mod 2)) / 2)^2`

For example, from 4 to 9:

`((9 + (9 mod 2)) / 2)^2 - ((4 - (4 mod 2)) / 2)^2 
= ((9 + 1) / 2)^2 - ((4 - 0) / 2)^2
= (10 / 2)^2 - (4 / 2)^2
= (5)^2 - (2)^2 = 25 - 4 = 21`

To confirm, 5 + 7 + 9 = 21

Even looks a bit more intimidating. It would be:
`(((b - (b mod 2)) / 2)^2 + ((b - (b mod 2)) / 2)) - ((((a + (a mod 2)) - 2) / 2)^2 + (((a + (a mod 2)) - 2) / 2)`

So, evens from 6 to 11 (6 + 8 + 10 = 24):

`(((11 - (11 mod 2)) / 2)^2 + ((11 - (11 mod 2)) / 2)) - ((((6 + (6 mod 2)) - 2) / 2)^2 + (((6 + (6 mod 2)) - 2) / 2) 
= (((11 - 1) / 2)^2 + ((11 - 1) / 2)) - ((((6 + 0) - 2) / 2)^2 + (((6 + 0) - 2) / 2)
= ((10 / 2)^2 + (10 / 2)) - (((6 - 2) / 2)^2 + ((6 - 2) / 2))
= ((5)^2 + 5) - ((4 / 2)^2 + (4 / 2))
= (25 + 5) - ((2)^2 + 2) = 30 - (4 + 2) = 24`

Answer (score 0):

For even numbers the sum is (n / 2)^2 + n / 2
so 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 = ( 8 / 2 )^2 + ( 8 / 2 ) = 16 + 4 = 20

So for a series a..b again with both a and b included, the sum of even numbers is:
((b / 2)^2 + ( b / 2 )) - ((a / 2)^2 + ( a / 2 ))